# Import all database links using dbms_datapump

Tags: oracle, database-link, datapump

> Source DB version:      11.2.0.3
>   Destination DB version: 12.1.0.2

I'm attempting to import all database links from one database to another using dbms_datapump.  The code is running on the above destination DB, and pulling the DB Links from the above Source DB via a Database Link.

I've used dbms_datapump.metadata_filter in the past to only import certain objects (like functions or procedures).  However, the following returns ORA-39001: invalid argument value:

```
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(h1,'INCLUDE_PATH_EXPR','IN (''DATABASE LINK'')');
```

Therefore, I tried the plural version which also returned ORA-39001:

```
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(h1,'INCLUDE_PATH_EXPR','IN (''DATABASE LINKS'')');
```

I know I must be missing something basic here, but searching on this issue has been annoying since search results with "dbms_datapump" and "database link" in the same search has only returned results with how to import over a Database link, and not how to import the Database Links directly.

I used to be able to import the Database Links directly using:

```
select DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR@dblinkimp(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL@dblinkimp
('DB_LINK', '[DBlinkName]', '[SchemaName]')) from dual@dblinkimp;
```

Then I would run the output from the above statement using execute immediate, but this is no longer a valid option starting in 11.2.0.4 (See Metalink Doc ID 1905221.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `DATABASE LINK` or `DATABASE LINKS`, it is `DB_LINK`. You can find the valid values in `DATABASE_EXPORT_OBJECTS`, `SCHEMA_EXPORT_OBJECTS` and `TABLE_EXPORT_OBJECTS`.

Comment: And now I feel silly. I couldn't find the list of supported values for INCLUDE_PATH_EXPR either through searches or via the Oracle Docs (doesn't mean they arn't there.. probably just means I missed it). I appreciate your help